# Why does Svg path appears in console but not on screen?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I was wondering if anyone could lend me a hand.

I'm trying to render a map of Singapore from the following [topoJSON](https://gist.github.com/ceocookie/20ac1c6fc99a79b85cdc822e9996ac80?short_path=90cd376) which I had converted.

Below is my code:

```
<style>
    path {
        /*fill: #ccc;*/
        stroke: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.96);
        stroke-linejoin: round;
    }
</style>
    <svg width="900" height="600"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>
     var svg = d3.select("svg"),
         width = +svg.attr("width"),
         height = +svg.attr("height");

//     var projection = d3.geoAlbers();
     var projection = d3.geoMercator()
         .center([0, 5 ])
         .scale(900)
         .rotate([-180,0]);

     var path = d3.geoPath(projection);

    d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.json, "data/sgtopo.json")
        .await(ready);

    function ready(error, sg){
        if(error) throw error;
        var topofeature = topojson.feature(sg, sg.objects["sg-"]);
        svg.append("g")
         .selectAll("path")
         .data(topofeature.features)
         .enter()
         .append("path")
         .attr("d", path);


    }
</script>
</html>
```

While i see the path generated on the console: the page remains blank.
Would appreciate any help please thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to regenerate the issue (chart is not rendering at all), can you create a snippet here or on jsfiddle, for JSON file data, you can use some dummy object.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking time to respond, appreciate it. Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzx5rnzy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the other answer's comments, the drawing takes place off the screen. This is a common problem with troubleshooting d3.js maps: no errors are thrown but no data is visibly drawn. When this is the case, usually the issue is you have chosen incorrect projection parameters.

If I substitute your topojson for a world json this is my result:

[image]

It is centered at 180 degrees east/west and five degrees north. This is centered in the Pacific, east of Indonesia. Singapore, however, is at ~104 degrees east and ~1 degree north. So your projection parameters should be more like:

```
     var projection = d3.geoMercator()
     .center([103.833333, 1.283333 ])
     .scale(900)
```

In fact, your scale could be much larger, in order to zoom in further. With a scale of 900 and the center specified above, I get something like this:

[image]

Using

```
     var projection = d3.geoMercator()
     .center([103.833333, 1.283333 ])
     .scale(60000)
```

and your data (and code from above), I got something like:

[image]

Also, with a Mercator projection, you do not need to use rotate as the map is properly aligned no matter where you center it (unlike with, say, conical projections). Simply centering it on the coordinate that is at the center of your feature is sufficient.

Comment: Hey thanks so much! I was just wondering for future tasks, how do i go about identifying my projection parameters?

Comment: Projection choice can be tricky, as are the parameters for it. There is more here to say then a comment allows. Generally with a mercator in non-polar areas you can center it on the longitude and latitude at the center of your area of interest. Starting with a small scale (say 200) can help you see if your area of interest is positioned in or near the center. For many areas there are standardized map projections which are listed online on sites such as spatialreference.org/. Converting these for use in d3 is generally not too difficult, and many questions on SO help in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `stroke` to your path because it is white by default.

```
svg.append("g")
     .selectAll("path")
     .data(topofeature.features)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", path)
     .attr("stroke", "black"); <-- Add this
```

Comment: Hey @Dummy thanks for taking time to answer, I just tried but still nothing appeared on the screen. I was thinking that the style configured in path would have already made it lack in color

Comment: @cookiedookie your path is moved off the viewport of the containing `svg` look at the coordinates of your path, it first moves to **negative** 715 horizontally, which is not within the viewport of your `svg`